# find folders with no further subfolders in perl

Tags: perl, find

How do I find, in a given path, all folders with no further subfolders? They may contain files but no further folders.

For example, given the following directory structure:

```
time/aa/
time/aa/bb
time/aa/bb/something/*
time/aa/bc
time/aa/bc/anything/*
time/aa/bc/everything/*
time/ab/
time/ab/cc
time/ab/cc/here/*
time/ab/cc/there/*
time/ab/cd
time/ab/cd/everywhere/*
time/ac/
```

The output of `find(time)` should be as follows:

```
time/aa/bb/something/*
time/aa/bc/anything/*
time/aa/bc/everything/*
time/ab/cc/here/*
time/ab/cc/there/*
time/ab/cd/everywhere/*
```

`*` above represents files.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where did you get stuck, what is your question about the code you've already written? We're not a "write a solution for me" site. You can take a look at File::Find if you don't know where to start: http://search.cpan.org/~dom/perl-5.12.5/lib/File/Find.pm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Any* time you want to write a directory walker, **always** use the standard [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind) module. When dealing with the filesystem, you have to be able to handle odd corner cases, and naïve implementations rarely do.

The [environment provided to the callback](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind#The_wanted_function) (named `wanted` in the documentation) has three variables that are particularly useful for what you want to do.

> `$File::Find::dir` is the current directory name
>
> `$_` is the current filename within that directory
>
> `$File::Find::name` is the complete pathname to the file

When we find a directory that is not `.` or `..`, we record the complete path and delete its parent, which we now know cannot be a leaf directory. At the end, any recorded paths that remain must be leaves because [`find` in File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind#find) performs a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

@ARGV = (".") unless @ARGV;

my %dirs;
sub wanted {
  return unless -d && !/^\.\.?\z/;
  ++$dirs{$File::Find::name};
  delete $dirs{$File::Find::dir};
}

find \&wanted, @ARGV;
print "$_\n" for sort keys %dirs;
```

You can run it against a subdirectory of the current directory

```
$ leaf-dirs time
time/aa/bb/something
time/aa/bc/anything
time/aa/bc/everything
time/ab/cc/here
time/ab/cc/there
time/ab/cd/everywhere
```

or use a full path

```
$ leaf-dirs /tmp/time
/tmp/time/aa/bb/something
/tmp/time/aa/bc/anything
/tmp/time/aa/bc/everything
/tmp/time/ab/cc/here
/tmp/time/ab/cc/there
/tmp/time/ab/cd/everywhere
```

or plumb multiple directories in the same invocation.

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar/baz/quux
$ leaf-dirs /tmp/time /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo/bar/baz/quux
/tmp/time/aa/bb/something
/tmp/time/aa/bc/anything
/tmp/time/aa/bc/everything
/tmp/time/ab/cc/here
/tmp/time/ab/cc/there
/tmp/time/ab/cd/everywhere
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you open the root folder and use following procedure:

```
sub child_dirs {
    my ($directory) = @_;
```

1. **Open** the directory

   ```
   opendir my $dir, $directory or die $!;
   ```
2. **select** the files **from** the files in this directory **where** the file is a directory

   ```
   my @subdirs = grep {-d $_ and not m</\.\.?$>} map "$directory/$_", readdir $dir;
   #                  ^-- directory and not . or ..  ^-- use full name
   ```
3. **If** the list of such selected files contains elements,
   3.1. **then** recurse into each such directory,
   3.2. **else** this directory is a "leaf" and it will be appended to the output files.

   ```
   if (@subdirs) {
      return map {child_dirs($_)} @subdirs;
   } else {
      return "$directory/*";
   }
   # OR: @subdirs ? map {child_dirs($_)} @subdirs : "$directory/*";
   ```

.

```
}
```

Example usage:

```
say $_ for child_dirs("time"); # dir `time' has to be in current directory.
```

Comment: Nice use of grep to shorten things up!

Answer (score 0):

This function will do it. Just call it with your initial path:

```
sub isChild {

  my $folder = shift;
  my $isChild = 1;

    opendir(my $dh, $folder) || die "can't opendir $folder: $!";
    while (readdir($dh)) {
      next if (/^\.{1,2}$/); # skip . and ..
      if (-d "$folder/$_") {
        $isChild = 0;
        isChild("$folder/$_");
      }
    }

    closedir $dh;

    if ($isChild) { print "$folder\n"; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the readdir way of doing things. Then I stumbled upon this...

```
  use File::Find::Rule;
  # find all the subdirectories of a given directory
  my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->in( $directory );
```

I eliminated any entry matching the initial part of the string and not having some of the leaf entries, from this output.